# No result from callback function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to execute callback function

```
function recurring_end() {

var sql= "SELECT `bookmarks`.`id`,`bookmarks`.`bookmark_url` as url FROM bookmarks LIMIT 0, 10";

connection.query(sql, function(err,bookmarks) {
     for(var i = 0; i< bookmarks.length; i++){
        (function(i) {

                parseArticle(i,function(err,result){
                    console.log("Result is "+JSON.stringify(result));
                        NewParseArtilce(result,function() {
                                console.log("New Parse Artilce is " +i);
                    });

                });
         })(i);
     }
});
}
function NewParseArtilce(i,callback){
    console.log("New Article Number is is "+i);

}
function parseArticle(i,callback) {
    console.log("Parse Article Number is " +i);

return i;
};
```

This is my code.  I am executing parseArticle Function first and then i want to pass result into **newParseArticle** But i am not getting any result in parseArtilce.

Any idea, why it is causing problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `parseArticle` is synchronous. It should be:

```
function parseArticle(i, callback) {
  console.log("Parse Article Number is " +i);
  callback(null, i); // executes the callback, null is err and i is result
}
```

Also your last `console.log` won't get executed. You should do this:

```
function NewParseArtilce(i,callback){
  console.log("New Article Number is is "+i);
  callback(); // executes the callback
}
```

Comment: what is null.  How you do you this is synchronous or asynchronous please

Comment: @HituBansal Simply put, when using `callback` = **asynchronous**. When using `return` = **synchronous**. [Understand Callbacks](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/).